# Oracle : Select Values from same table (JOIN)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

I need to select values from this table where `NDI` in list of values and `DATE_ISSUE = DATE_ISSUE_MAX` for every value in `NDI` list.

I have this table :

[image: | NDI | DATE_ISSUE |]

when executing :

```
SELECT NDI
FROM OM_DB.FT_PFS_SBC_TICKETS
WHERE NDI in ('0556254201','0559592626')
AND DATE_ISSUE=(
    SELECT MAX(DATE_ISSUE) 
    FROM OM_DB.FT_PFS_SBC_TICKETS
);
```

I get `NDI EMPTY`:

[image: | NDI |]

Instead of:

[image: | NDI | DATE_ISSUE |]

Comment: Yes it's oracle Sharma

Comment: The `max(DATE_ISSUE)` of that table is `31/10/17` for NDI `0559321162`. For your provided NDIs there is no entry with the max date.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are other methods, you want a correlated subquery for this approach:

```
select t.NDI
from OM_DB.FT_PFS_SBC_TICKETS t
where t.NDI in ('0556254201', '0559592626') and
      t.DATE_ISSUE = (SELECT MAX(t2.DATE_ISSUE)
                      FROM OM_DB.FT_PFS_SBC_TICKETS t2
                      WHERE t2.NDI = t.NDI
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `max(DATE_ISSUE)` of that table is `31/10/17` for NDI `0559321162`. For your provided NDIs there is no entry with the max date.

You should add the `in` clause also to the sub-query or make it a correlated query

Answer (score 0):

Yous should  compare the value related  to each NDI

```
  select NDI
  from OM_DB.FT_PFS_SBC_TICKETS
  where NDI in ('0556254201','0559592626')
  and (NDI, DATE_ISSUE)  =(SELECT NDI, MAX(DATE_ISSUE) 
            FROM OM_DB.FT_PFS_SBC_TICKETS GROUP BY NDI);
```

or

```
  select T1.NDI
  from OM_DB.FT_PFS_SBC_TICKETS T1
  INNER JOIN ( SELECT NDI, MAX(DATE_ISSUE)  my_date
            FROM OM_DB.FT_PFS_SBC_TICKETS 
            GROUP BY NDI ) T2 on T2.NDI =  T1.NDI AND T2.my_date = T1.DATE_ISSUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this query can be simplified like this:

```
SELECT NDI, MAX(DATE_ISSUE) 
FROM OM_DB.FT_PFS_SBC_TICKETS WHERE NDI in('0556254201', '0559592626') GROUP BY NDI;
```